# have only the year of the citation colored

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib, bibliographystyle

I want only the year of the citation in blue, NOT everything like it its now.

**LaTeX**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks=false,             
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
    
    This is an example of ... \citep{author1}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

**Bibliography.bib**

```
@book{author1,
  title={Book Title},
  author={Author},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You should load either `natbib` or `apalike`, *but not both*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took some time to find the right call to `\NAT@hyper@` to patch.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author1,
  title={Book Title},
  author={Author},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %hidelinks,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=blue
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\NAT@citex
 {%
  \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
    \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
    \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
    \NAT@date
  }%
 }
 {%
  \@citea
  \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
  \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar
  \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
 }
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd\NAT@citex
 {%
  \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
    \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
    \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
    {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
    \NAT@date
  }%
 }
 {
  \@citea
    \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
    \NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi
    \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
 }
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is an example of ... \citep{author1}.
    
This is an example of ... \citet{author1}.
    
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works correctly with `\citep`, but does not appear to work as it should with `\citet`.

Comment: thanks! if you can make that work for \citet too then I will select your answer. Unfortunately I have no clue what you did there...

Comment: @LeoFr I added also the patch for `\citet`

Comment: You may want to ask the moderator team to move your answer, which employs the `xpatch` package, to the earlier query, which so far has only one answer which, in turn, is based on the `etoolbox` package. That way, readers can compare and contrast the two solution methods more easily. Just a thought.